# ‘Symmetry’ of standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

Let D be a (finite) set of data points. E.g., D might contain people’s heights, their exam results, or the temperature of an object at various times. Further, let *m* be D’s mean, and let *s* be D’s standard deviation. Then there’s a sense in which *s* is ‘symmetric’ around *m*: for one thing, values in *m*-*s* are usually considered just as ‘normal’ or ‘standard’ as the values in *m*+*s*. For another thing, we can ‘rotate’ D around *m* without affecting *s*: If each *d* ∈ D is replaced with *d*+2(*m*-*d*), the resulting set will have the same standard deviation as the original set. (E.g., if *m* = 10 and 7 ∈ D, then when we ‘rotate’ D around *m*, 7 would be replaced with 7+2(10-7) = 13.) Thirdly, I’ve noticed the following (slightly more interesting) fact:

For each *d* ∈ D, we can find a number *d'*, s.th. if *d* is replaced with *d'* in D (while the rest of D stays the same), then the resulting set D' will have the same standard deviation as the original set.

The number *d'* in question will usually be close to, but distinct from, *d*+2(*m*-*d*). The mean of the new set will usually be different from the mean of the original set. (I say ‘usually’ because if all elements of D are the same, then *d* = *d'* = *m* = *d*+2(*m*-*d*).) As one would expect, D' can be ‘rotated’ again without affecting the standard deviation, and each element of the rotated D' can again be replaced without affecting the standard deviation; and so forth.

Now, my question is: are there other ways in which the standard deviation could be said to be ‘symmetric’, and is its ‘symmetry’ ever relevant in practice, when doing statistics/data analysis. Also, is there any theoretical interest/value in exploring the ‘symmetry’ of the standard deviation? (I’m very new to statistics, so please forgive me if the question has an obvious / boring answer.)

Comment: Note that visually $d \mapsto d + 2(m-d)$ corresponds to reflecting $d$ through $m$.

Comment: I'm not sure this comment is relevant to your question but as far as I understand you may find interesting the ['Datasaurus Dozen'](https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats) dataset, where sets of points have pretty similar statistics but look essentially different.

Comment: @Denis Korzhenkov I *do* find this interesting: thanks! My question arose when I tried to understand what the standard deviation actually measures. Most sources say it measures how the data points are ‘spread out’. Yet then I noticed the results I mentioned, and that challenges this interpretation at least a little bit: when *d’* is substituted for *d*, there’s an intuitive sense in which the data is now ‘spread’ differently as the graph now looks different. So, it goes in the same direction as the Datasaurus.